# How to get the approvalURL for PayPal Plus integration?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I followed the official instructions: https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/emea/de/de/paypal-plus-center/PayPal_PLUS_integration_guide.pdf

**08. Integrating PayPal PLUS**

> Prior to rendering the payment wall a payment resource must be
>   created. The  corresponding API call is “create payment”. When
>   creating the payment resource  am ount, currency and items details
>   must be submitted.

..Okay. Understand. So i need to Create a Payment, grab the Url and then i can render the PayPalPlus-Object finally.

I followed https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php as example script and one ohter. But i cant receive anything from $payment->getApprovalLink()

am i completely wrong?

which example can i use to create a payment and render the paypal-plus thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
'xxx',     // ClientID
'xxx'      // ClientSecret
)
);

$apiContext->setConfig(
array(
'mode' => 'sandbox'
)
);

$item1 = new \PayPal\Api\Item();
$item1->setName('Test item')
->setCurrency('USD')
->setQuantity(1)
->setPrice(1);

$itemList = new \PayPal\Api\ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1));

$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD');
$amount->setTotal('1');

$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);
$transaction->setItemList($itemList);
//$transaction->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());
//$transaction->setDescription('Description');

$redirectUrl = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrl->setReturnUrl('http://localhost');
$redirectUrl->setCancelUrl('http://localhost');

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrl);
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

$payment = $payment->create($apiContext);

$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

echo $approvalUrl;
```